# PHP invoke method inside Iterator

Tags: php, methods, iterator

I'm a beginner in object oriented, I would like to know if it is possible using some cast, magic method, or object oriented engineering to invoke what in the comment code below ?

Thanks in advance
A.pe

```
<?php
Class myArrayObj  {
    public $myArray ;

    function __construct(){
        $this->myArray = array( 
    0 => 'a', 
    1 => array('subA','subB',array(0 => 'subsubA', 1 => 'subsubB', 2 => array(0 => 'deepA', 1 => 'deepB'))), 
    2 => 'b', 
    3 => array('subA','subB','subC'), 
    4 => 'c'
    );
    }

    function getNumber() {
        return count($this->myArray);   
    }
}

$a = new myArrayObj();

$i = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($i as $key => $value) {
$type = gettype($value);
$depth = $i->getDepth();

if($i->hasChildren()) {
        echo "$depth: $key ($type) has children<br>";
        /* here is it possible to call ....->getNumber(); */
    } 
    else {
        echo "$depth: $key ($type) has no children<br>";
        /* here is it possible to call ....->getNumber(); */
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply do `$a->getNumber()`, but I feel like I'm not understanding the question properly here.

Comment: "f it is possible using some cast, magic method, or object oriented engineering to invoke what in the comment code below ?" - No. Because the relation with the original object is broken. `RecursiveArrayIterator` will cast the object to array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call like this:

```
$a->getNumber();
```

Here `$a` is an object of `myArrayObj` class. You can call any `property` and `method` from outside of the class based on its `access modifier`.

Full Code:

```
<?php
Class myArrayObj  {
    public $myArray ;

    function __construct(){
        $this->myArray = array( 
    0 => 'a', 
    1 => array('subA','subB',array(0 => 'subsubA', 1 => 'subsubB', 2 => array(0 => 'deepA', 1 => 'deepB'))), 
    2 => 'b', 
    3 => array('subA','subB','subC'), 
    4 => 'c'
    );
    }

    function getNumber() {
        return count($this->myArray);
    }

    function countArray($ar) {
        return count($ar);
    }
}

$a = new myArrayObj();

$i = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($i as $key => $value) {
$type = gettype($value);
$depth = $i->getDepth();

if($i->hasChildren()) {
        echo "$depth: $key ($type) has children<br>";
        /* here is it possible to call ....->getNumber(); */
        echo $a->countArray($value);
    } 
    else {
        echo "$depth: $key ($type) has no children<br>";
        /* here is it possible to call ....->getNumber(); */
        echo $a->countArray($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, my intent it is call the ->getName() over $i RecursiveIterator.

Comment: For each array deriver inside the main array get the count element... not always the coutn of Main array... it is more clear now?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just call the method where ever you need.

Comment: Can you implement that or want from me ? First try yourself.

Comment: I spent some time yesterday, I tried to $i->getName() but of course that is not possible because thare aren't any relationship between RecursiveIteratorIterator and myArrayObj, I tried to extend the myArrayObj with RecursiveIteratorIterator but no result... I have to make some cast?

Comment: Yes please! show me how must be implemented... thanks